# Angularjs. How to connected fields in form with selectbox. Changing select should change fields

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to make input form.
I have select with options. After choosing one of the options i want three other fields to fill, according to selected option.

For example:

If user selects Option1 3 other field should have text 1_1, 1_2, 1_3 in them.
If user selects Option2 3 other field should have text 2_1, 2_2, 2_3 in them.

What is the best way to do this?

I found this way:

Creating variable in scope

```
$scope.select_options = [
    {"name": "Option1",
        "field1": "1_1",
        "field2": "1_2",
        "field3": "1_3"},
    {"name": "Option2",
        "field1": "2_1",
        "field2": "2_2",
        "field3": "2_3"},
    {"name": "Option3",
        "field1": "3_1",
        "field2": "3_2",
        "field3": "3_3"}
];
```

and this is html code

```
    <select ng-model="opt_select"
        ng-options="option as option.name for option in select_options"
        ng-init="opt_select = opt_select || select_options[0]" id="well"
        name="company" class="input"></select>
<input id="field1" name="field1" placeholder="" class="input" type="text"
       ng-model="opt_select.field1">
<input id="field3" name="field2" placeholder="" class="input" type="text"
       ng-model="opt_select.field2">
<input id="field3" name="field3" placeholder="" class="input" type="text"
       ng-model="opt_select.field3">
```

Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.
Here is the fiddle for it:[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yXVSb/)

But of course, because it's two way binded to your view, your `field`'s in your `select_options` will be saved if user edits the input box. That is, if user changes the `field1` of `Option3` to 3_1_new by editing it in input box,it will still be 3_1_new when user selects another option and selects the `Option3` back. If this does not fit your use-case you have to think of something else.

Apart from that, for best practices and other code review you should post to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/